# How to monitor the size of spark's "STATE"?

Tags: memory, apache-spark, state, spark-streaming, rdd

How to monitor the size of state of spark streaming application? The storage tab in driver GUI is only showing the results of Mapwithstate operation (Mapwithstaterdd, but not the actual Spark State RDD!

From Grafana, we observed the overall memory usage of spark streaming application "grows" with each batch of incoming stream processing. The memory usage by worker nodes (overall cluster) shown in the Grafana is much higher than the Mapwithstaterdd's (results of mapwithstate operation) size under Storage tab in driver GUI.

I stopped feeding input data for about 30 mins, but the memory usage never comes down. I suspect the bulk of the memory is consumed by spark 'state'. Is there a way i can monitor the size of the spark 'state'?

Comment: *"Mapwithstaterdd, but not the actual Spark State RDD"* What does actual Spark State mean? The state is held via the RDD abstraction. Also, when do you release the state? The fact that you don't send any new data doesn't mean the stateful stream will discard its state.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's not able to check directly.

From the "Storage" page in Spark UI, we can get "Size in Memory" of the "MapWithStateRDD". But it contains the input data of that batch and the state.

As [Understanding Spark Caching](http://sujee.net/2015/01/22/understanding-spark-caching/#.W_Enk5P7RQK), the memory cost will be about 3 times bigger than the data size.

And by default, Spark will cache 2 * 10 (checkpointDuration) MapWithStateRDDs.

So, the total memory cost is large.